# file_exists() or is_readable()

Tags: php, include, require, file-exists

Which one should you use when you want to include a PHP file?

```
if(file_exists($file) require "$file";
```

or

```
if(is_readable($file) require "$file";
```

?

Answer (score 40):

> `file_exists()` or `is_readable()`
>   Which one should you use when you want to include a PHP file?

This depends on if you want to know if *only* a file *or* a directory exists, or if either is fine, and if you need to check if readable or not.

Sometimes you only care the file and/or directory exist, and don't need to read, sometimes you also need to read.

### Options

[**file_exists()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Checks whether a **file** or **directory** exists.

If you explicitly only want to know if a *file* exists, this will return false positives as will return true if it's a directory.

[**is_readable()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

Tells whether a **file** or **directory** exists and is readable.

If you explicitly only want to know if a *file* is readable, this is likely to return false positives as could return true if it's a directory.

---

Additional options you've not mentioned, but probably need:

[**is_file()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

Tells whether it exists and is a regular **file** (not a directory).

[**is_dir()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

Tells whether it exists and is a **directory** (not a file).

### Solution & Answer

If you want to check exists and:

1. Is only a file: Use `is_file()`
2. Is only a dir: Use `is_dir()`
3. Is file or dir: Use `file_exists()`

If you want to check exists and is readable:

1. And is only file: Use `is_file()` and `is_readable()`
2. And is only dir: Use `is_dir()` and `is_readable()`
3. And is file or dir: Use `is_readable()`

You don't need to use `file_exists()` and `is_readable()` together because `is_readable()` also checks if `file_exists()`.
Pairing `is_readable()` with either `is_file()` or `is_dir()` is only to check if is readable *specifically* on a file only or  *specifically* on a directory only.

---

### Relying on require

As with most PHP and "what is the best approach/function/etc" - it depends on the scenario.

Relying on just `require` to manage if the system hangs or not is not really useful. Imagine the required file is not available, so PHP halts as require fails, but the file is simply an article image or user avatar - do you really not want to serve site navigation, logo, links, all kinds of page text and content just because of a missing article image?

VITAL:
If the file is a database connection class, which allows serving of the entire page content, then the file not being there likely requires a system halt.
Of course then you should have some kind of exit strategy, such as serving a 404 page, or an error message - "Sorry there was a fault, we will look into it" etc.

NON VITAL:
It's sometimes valid for the file to not exist, or at least not detrimental to the rest of the application.
Such as if an image file does not exist, you could serve a message or default image, such as a user avatar will just have a default avatar if theirs is not found.

Comment: Great and best answer so far! +1

Comment: Use `is_file()` check for a missing article image, to avoid unnecessary  warnings and errors.

Comment: In a legacy code base, I've stumbled upon `@require "CustomConst.php";`. The intention is that the file is optional, so, @require will just silently ignore if it's not there. Now, this doesn't work in php 7.4, so I want to replace it with something like `if (is_readable('...')) { require_once '...'; }`. The question is: will `is_readable()` scan all include dirs (like `require_once` does)? If not, it's functionally not the same replacement :(

Comment: @pilat if "the file is optional" perhaps using `include` is better suited? not sure if that helps the issue though

Comment: @James well, this is in one of legacy projects. We have `@require_once "CustomConst.php"` in there, which, I guess, have worked in earlier versions, but in php7.4 it generates an error. My first instinct was to replace it with `if (file_exists(...)) { require_once "CustomConst.php"; }`, but the next question was: where is this file expected to be. Obviously, @require_once would search for it in all the "include_dirs", but `file_exists()` would not. 

Finally, I've found this thingie: `if (stream_resolve_include_path('CustomConst.php') !== false) ...`. This must work as expected

Answer (score 10):

If your going to `require` a file, there's no point in error checking. The point of using `require` instead of `include` is to hault execution of the script when the file does not exist.

If you don't care if the file exists, just use `include`.

Comment: but what if you're not sure the file exists?

Comment: `require` is used to make sure the file is there before continuing. If that file **is required**, it will throw an error if the file isnt there. If the file isn't crucial to your page, then use `include`.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is: **is_readable()**.

> bool is_readable ( string $filename )
>
> Tells whether a file exists and is
> readable.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Comment: Yeah, but further below it says "Returns TRUE if the file or *directory* specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise."

Comment: This is the CORRECT answer. Applying "&& is_file($filename)" for extra transparency over folders is suggested because they return true also.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (is_file($file) && is_readable($file))
```

because `is_readable($file)` can be `true` also for directories.